# set class on specific screen size (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, column-count

I am working with bootstrap.

And would like to load several classes depending on screen size, like sm-col, xs.col.

Example: Got a text id

```
<div id="text" class="xs-format lg-format ..."></div>

style = 
.sm-format{
 column-count: 3;
}

.xs-format{
 column-count: 1;
}

.lg-format{
 column-count: 5;
}
```

It should load text in 1 column if xs screen is loading, 3 columns on sm screens and 5 on lg screens.

Any hint?

Regards
n00n

Comment: Why not use media queries?

Comment: Would like to use bootstrap only, .. media queries is a solution, but I am sure there is something in bootstrap to solve things like this.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Bootstrap doesn't "load" classes on elements. It uses media queries to apply CSS styles that contain certain classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into Bootstrap's [card columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns), but you're going to have to edit the media queries if you want more than 3 columns on larger screen sizes.